# How to join and count the results of two SQL queries on the same table

Tags: sql

I have one table that contains all kind of metadata about customers. It is structured like this:

```
customer_id, metadata_id, text_value
```

I want to count all customers that have a specific `text_value` for `metadata_id='metadata_1'` and for whom an entry for `metadata_id='metadata_2'` exists.

| customer_id | metadata_id | text_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer_1 | metadata_1 | yes! |
| customer_1 | metadata_2 | random value |
| customer_2 | metadata_1 | yes! |
| customer_2 | metadata_2 | never mind |
| customer_3 | metadata_1 | no! |
| customer_3 | metadata_2 | another value |
| customer_4 | metadata_1 | yes! |

I can easily get the two parts:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM my_table
WHERE metadata_id='metadata_1' AND text_value='yes!';

SELECT customer_id
FROM my_table
WHERE metadata_id='metadata_2';
```

But how do I combine them and count them?

Here `customer_1` and `customer_2` fulfil both conditions. So the answer for the example would be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM my_table T
WHERE metadata_id='metadata_1' AND text_value='yes!'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table D WHERE D.customer_id=T.customer_id AND D.metadata_id='metadata_2')
```

If there is a duplicate ids and and you want to count only distinct ids you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)`.

And if you want to get the customer ids:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM my_table T
WHERE metadata_id='metadata_1' AND text_value='yes!'
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table D WHERE D.customer_id=T.customer_id AND D.metadata_id='metadata_2')
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CYyOvBp8).

Answer (score 2):

We mark the `customer_id` that follows condition one. Then we mark the `customer_id` that follows condition two and then we count the  `customer_id` we have left.

```
select  count(distinct customer_id) as cnt
from   (
       select  *
               ,count(case when metadata_id = 'metadata_1' and text_value = 'yes!' then 1 end) over(partition by customer_id) as mrk1 
               ,count(case when metadata_id = 'metadata_2' then 1 end) over(partition by customer_id) as mrk2
       from    t
       ) t
where  mrk1 > 0 
and    mrk2 > 0
```

| cnt |
| --- |
| 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9UOSMIWb)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it

```
;WITH
  T1
  AS
  (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE metadata_id='metadata_1' AND text_value='yes!'
  ),
  T2
  AS
  (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE metadata_id='metadata_2'
  )
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM T1
    INNER JOIN
    T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION` should work I think

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_id)
FROM (
        SELECT customer_id
        FROM my_table
        WHERE metadata_id = 'metadata_1'
            AND text_value = 'yes!'
        UNION
        SELECT customer_id
        FROM my_table
        WHERE metadata_id = 'metadata_2'
    ) alpha;
```

Comment: You are right, I assumed OP wants to exclude duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use OR operator and merge your conditions.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            customer_id
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            ( ( metadata_id= 'metadata_1' AND text_value= 'yes!' )
              OR metadata_id= 'metadata_2' )
        GROUP BY
            customer_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

Comment: What happens if you have two rows where metadata_id= 'metadata_2'  for example?

Comment: I inserted the sample data (it has three rows with metadata_id= 'metadata_2'), and the query returned the desired result, please test it.

Comment: I did and it gives the wrong answer. https://dbfiddle.uk/5RmVyJOl

Comment: the correct answer is 2 as mentioned in the last sentence of the question and my query return 2 as you provide in the link. I don't get why my query is wrong.

Comment: In the link I provided the answer should be one. You didn't look at the data.

Comment: here is a fiddle with your answer, my answer and another correct answer from here so you could see the difference in result: https://dbfiddle.uk/hI6gVglu

Comment: @DannySlor Dude! Your fiddle is wrong and biased. First off, you used `metadata_2` as negating example. `metadata_2` is specified in the question as an inclusion in the second query. If you use `metadata_3` in the first row of example instead, both queries return `1`. So, since using `metadata_2` for 1st row ShOULD return a value, the query in the answer returns the correct answer and not the one with distinct/windowing. Also, why use windowing when a simple grouping would do the (wrong) job? They're not as efficient.

Comment: You're assuming a condition can't happen twice for the same ID. This is a bad assumption to make.